# Workflow sample for Packer and Terraform integration

Tags: devops, terraform, vsphere, packer, esxi

I'm trying to create a lab for virtual machines in the VMWare Hypervisor to install a cluster in RHEL; I've seen that Packer and Terraform are very interesting but I can't find clear and /or detailed samples about their workflow, specifically how to create the image in Packer and then let that Terraform consume it. 
I have seen that Packer has build capabilities but even some type of deploy ones and I don't understand if these overlaps Terraform; I've read that some type of automation is possible via another HashiCorp product, Atlas, but I don't want to use it, at least at this stage of study and trial of the software.
So what I'd like to do is create a VMWare compatible virtual machine images with Packer (RHEL base plus other capabilities), pass them to a Terraform artifact that creates the vm in my esxi.

Hope to find guidance.

Comment: Create the image with Packer and then use it with the infrastructure you spin up with Terraform.

Comment: Thanks: any documentation or blog post that show how to pass image from Packer to Terraform; I've seen a blog post but it uses Atlas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure of your specific use case, but Terraform does have data-sources that make it easier to connect images built by Packer to Terraform: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html

Here is a partial example of using a Packer Built AMI for an AWS EC2 instance:

```
data "aws_ami" "bastion" {
  filter {
    name   = "state"
    values = ["available"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["Bastion"]
  }

  most_recent = true
}

resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  ami = "${data.aws_ami.bastion.id}"
  # ...
}
```

I have also used bash scripts to parse out Packer generated values and dump them into tfvars files, which Terraform consumed.

Comment: Thanks, great: I suppose it is possible because there is also a provider for VMWare vSphere; do you have any link to a blog post or other documentation material? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah sadly, I have not been able to find much in the way of documentation or blog posts, so I wrote up a couple for my use cases. [Here](http://www.davidbegin.com/packer-and-terraform-part-ii-data-sources/)'s my post expanding on my example above.

And [here](http://www.davidbegin.com/packer-and-terraform/) is one for my bash hack. These are both specific to AWS EC2 and building an AMI though, so they might not help you get much further. However If you have a project hosting somewhere with the Packer and Terraform portions built but not connected,
I could take a look.

Comment: Thanks Begin for your great help, your post is plenty of information and tips. I'll try to contact you when I have some material available.